# TBC files from an old and unknown database system

Tags: database, dos

I have a bunch of *.TBC files from a very old application that runs in MS-DOS called TURBOLAB. Anyone know which DB System use files with a TBC extension.

I've tried renaming the files to *.dbf to check if they are dBase files with no luck.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by the application and era (old MS-DOS) *.tbc is probably a fixed length binary record format written by the application's developers.

Try opening up the file in a text editor like TextPad first and if you can read the contents, if so I have a fixed length text file reader that you can adapt to your needs.  If you cannot you may need to determine field lengths and data types through trial and error.

Also, are there associated files for each *.tbc?  A paired file could indicate field lengths and data types (or that information could be stored at the top of a *.tbc file itself).

Comment: Ruh roh if this is the Stemmer Turbolab and not the Turbolab dental software you're looking at audio recordings in some oddball format I'm sure.

Answer (score 0):

I Googled this: [FlexPro](http://www.adeptscience.co.uk/products/dataanal/flexpro/import.html). I hope it helps. Sounds pricey, I hope your data is worth it.

Answer (score 0):

> Judging by the application and era
>   (old MS-DOS) *.tbc is probably a fixed
>   length binary record format written by
>   the application's developers.

I think you are right. Unfortunately there are no matching file names. If each of those files is a 'table', there are like ~150 tables in this database. Too much work for such an old app. I guess my customer will have to start from scratch using my app.

Thanks anyway for your help.

Comment: Its possible that the files have header information that describe fields, data types, and lengths (in lieu of parallel header files, like FoxPro did).  It /may/ not be hard to interpret it after a few hours of work and your customers will love you for it (plus very good experience).